# Fetching related entity in single query in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have two entities that look kind of like this:

```
@Entity
class TimeRange(
    @Id val id: UUID,
    val startTime: Instant,
    val endTime: Instant,
    ...
)

@Entity
class StepInProcess(
    @Id val id: UUID,
    val projectId: UUID,
    @OneToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "range_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    val timeRange: TimeRange,
    ...
)
```

My repository just looks like:

```
@Repository
interface StepInProcessRepository : JpaRepository<StepInProcess, UUID> {
    fun findAllByProjectId(projectId: UUID): List<StepInProcess>
}
```

Whenever I retrieve a list of steps, I pretty much always need to access the `startTime` on the associated `TimeRange`. Each one of these requires that a separate query be issued to retrieve the time range entity which ends up being really inefficient. Ideally I'd like to instruct Hibernate to always retrieve this data immediately, ideally with a join, rather than requiring a separate select.

It seemed like adding `@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)` to `timeRange` should do what I wanted, but this doesn't seem to be the case (or I've missed something else). I'm basing this on watching debug logs go by that show Hibernate issuing lots of `select` statements for `TimeRange` entities; not sure if there's a better way to diagnose this sort of thing.

Alternatively, I would be fine with promoting `startTime` and `endTime` to be properties on the Step itself, but I'm not clear on how to accomplish this, either. I do *not* want to create an inheritance relationship between the two entities as it's not really fair to say that a step "is a " time range.

Is `@Fetch` the right way to do this? If so, is there something more to getting it to work than adding the annotation to the property? If not, how should I go about tackling this?

Comment: This question seems to be related to the Fetch not working as expected, but doesn't really explain what was done to resolve the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457731/hibernate-issuing-select-statement-even-if-fetchmode-join

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like maybe `@Fetch` just doesn't work with JPA? Instead, modifying my repository to include an explicit query with `JOIN FETCH` seems to have done the job:

```
@Query("SELECT step FROM StepInProcess step JOIN FETCH step.timeRange WHERE step.projectId = :projectId")
fun findAllByProjectId(projectId: UUID): List<StepInProcess>
```

Not sure if that's the best route to go or not.